# Passing an extremely long filter to dotnet test?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli, dotnet-test

I am trying to pass an extremely long filter to `dotnet test --filter`. However, it is so long, that I get a "path too long" error.

Is there any other way to specify a filter?

Or alternatively somehow "pipe" a filter from a file into the `--filter` argument with `dotnet test`?

Comment: How does filter look like? Maybe it's just a path issue?

Comment: It's 63744 characters long. I'd rather not post it. And for less than approximately 30000 characters, it works.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request for the `dotnet` CLI to support "response" files. MSBuild and the C# compiler already do, but I don't think `dotnet` in general does. See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8725.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a OS limitation. not much you can do about it.

See: [Exec and (very) long commands on Windows](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2530)

> cmd.exe has a maximum command-line length limit of 8191 characters
> Win32's CreateProcess has a maximum lpCommandLine length of 32,768
> characters.

**Workaround**

See: [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20length%20of%20the,and%20all%20environment%20variable%20expansions.)

> Modify programs that require long command lines so that they use a
> file that contains the parameter information, and then include the
> name of the file in the command line.